# jQuery Form Validate, moving error message

Tags: jquery

Hi i'm using a simple jQuery validate script in which only requires the "`required`" class to be added. is there a way to make the error message about above the submit button rather than next to each field?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#theForm").validate();
  });
</script>
<form id="theForm">
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input class="required email" name="email" type="text" id="email" />

<label for="city">City</label>
<input name="city" type="text" id="city"  />
<input class="button" type="submit" value="SEND CONTACT FORM" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `errorplacement` function like as follows:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo('#errorcontainer-' + element.attr('id'));
    }
});
```

and can place the div near the submit button with an `id` like

```
 <div id="errorcontainer-city" class='errorDiv'></div>
```

so now the `error message` for the `city` field will be shown in this div. So you can place a div for email and other fields in the required place.

Comment: I put that code right after `$("#theForm").validate();` but no luck

Comment: Just put the code above the `validate()` function.It should work. If needed please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/dTtqj/